# Export list of lists with specified delimiter without FieldSeparator functionality

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I want to `Export` a list of lists in `Table` format with `\t` or `blank` as delimiter. Unfortunatelly **Mathematica 4.0** does not have the `FieldSeparator` option aviable.

Is there still a way to program this **without** the **FieldSeparator** command?

Example:

```
    list=Table[Random[Real,90],{2}]&/@Range[6];
```

I have searched this site and adapted an answer to a similar
[question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129102/how-to-export-csv-with-fixed-delimiter-and-specific-format-specifier?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
    Export["list.txt",({list[[All,1]],90-list[[All,2]]}//Transpose)/.x_?NumberQ:>ToString[NumberForm[x,NumberPoint->","]],"Table"];
```

Additionally to changing the `NumberPoint` I want 
the entries to have only a single delimiter character between the columns `list[[All,1]]` and `90-list[[All,2]]` in every line, i.e. a single spacebar or tab, to be able to import the data with another program.

The standard `Export` command however uses 4 times blank after padding every entry with blanks, which is an issue.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my lack of knowledge in formatting my questions properly!

Comment: We need to provide an answer that runs on *Mathematica* version 4.0? I imagine you could use [`Write`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Write.html) to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work with Mathematica version 4 :

```
list=Table[Random[Real,90],{2}]&/@Range[6];

myRiffleForMma4[l_List,elt_String]:=Insert[l,elt,List /@ Range[2,Length[l]]]

Export["test00.txt",
       StringJoin[
           myRiffleForMma4[
              StringJoin[myRiffleForMma4[#," "]]& /@ Map[ToString,list,{2}],
              "|"]
               ],
       "String"]
```

Mathematica 11.0 gives :

> 42.5872 74.261|86.0062 6.89626|75.0751 61.5735|44.216 83.7371|36.7864 2.49404|63.8472 36.3133

If you move to a newer Mathematica, you can replace `myRiffleForMa4[]` by the built-in function `Riffle[]` (introduced in version 6).

Comment: I may forget something that doesn't work with Mathematica 4. Please advice me.

Comment: Hey @andre, thank you for your answer! Unfortunatelly, Export doesn't recognize "String" as a format in Mma4... however your code works pretty good with "Table" instead! Thanks alot!